# How can I create and maintain machine-specific Visual C++ solution settings?

Tags: visual-c++, version-control, settings

My team has been developing a software package for a while. The code is under source version control. Until now, every developer has been setting up their own development environment manually (we use Visual C++, recently upgraded to 2012). Now that the structure of the project has grown more complicated and the build configuration is non-trivial, I decided to create a portable solution and add it to the source control system for the convenience of newcomers.

The problem is I need the developers to be able to set up the solution according to their particular needs (mostly preprocessor #define's) without disturbing the solution for everybody else.

VC++ is creating a .user file for every project that seems to be designed to hold settings on a per-user basis, but I'm not sure how to add settings so they are stored in this file (which I exclude from source control) and not in the project file or the property sheet files (which are included in source control).

How can I accomplish this? Thanks.

Comment: This is rather an unusual way to go about it.  Sounds like you are using #defines when you should be using configuration that's loaded at runtime.  Every programmer using the exact same solution and project files is a strong goal, especially essential when you use a build server.  And deliver a product that everybody can run and test the same way to repro bugs, the build result should always match.